# insert and delete functionality with ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I am working on basic functionality of insert,add,delete and update using **ajax**.
I have done little functionality write now..actually i want all functionality in a grid .

I put all html code inside a for loop.. this loop will execute till total num rows.. first execution of loop is fine, problem occur after this... next time when i click on delete button ajax call is not working.

Need help on this....

I have 2 files.. **form.php** and **operation.php**

code of form.php..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#delete").click(function(){ 
        var id=$("#uid").val();                   
        $.post("operation.php",{ID:id},function(data){
            $("#result").html(data);
        });               
    });
});

for($i=0;$i<2;$i++)
{        
    echo "<input type='text' value=".mysql_result($all_records, $i, "id")." name='uid' id='uid'>
    <input type='text' value=".mysql_result($all_records, $i,"name")." name='name' id='email' placeholder='Email'>  
    <input type='text' value=".mysql_result($all_records, $i,"email")." name='email' id='email' placeholder='Email'>
    <input type='password' value=".mysql_result($all_records, $i,"password")." name='pass' id='pass' placeholder='Password'>
    <input type='submit'name='delete' id='delete' value='Delete'>            
    <input  type='submit'name='update' id='update' value='Update'>";
    echo "</td></tr>";            
}
```

**operation.php**

write now i put only one line code for checking purpose...

```
echo  $_POST['ID'];
```

Comment: Html Ids are unique element so as i suppose you're looping and eventually It will create two same name of uid which will make a problem use class instead of id or make your uid unique.

Comment: ajax call working when i used class instead of id but it display same value every time... @SaadSuri

Answer (score 1):

Well i think you know that `id`s should have unique names. It is not a good idea to give same `id` to multiple elements in the same page.

I think the code bellow will solve your purpose.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".delete").click(function(){ 
        var id=$(this).data('id');
        $.post("operation.php",{ID:id},function(data){
            $("#result").html(data);
        });               
    });
});

for($i=0; $i<2; $i++)
{        
    echo "<input type='text' value='".mysql_result($all_records, $i, "id")."' name='uid' class='uid'>
    <input type='text' value='".mysql_result($all_records, $i,"name")."' name='name' class='name' placeholder='Email'>  
    <input type='text' value='".mysql_result($all_records, $i,"email")."' name='email' class='email' placeholder='Email'>
    <input type='password' value='".mysql_result($all_records, $i,"password")."' name='pass' class='pass' placeholder='Password'>
    <input type='button'name='delete' data-id='".mysql_result($all_records, $i, "id")."' class='delete' value='Delete'>            
    <input  type='submit' name='update' class='update' value='Update'>";
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
```

Try to understand it and compare it with your previous code.
Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Happy to know that :)